# MongoDB convert field in array of documents to different data type

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

I have a document with an array of documents, where I'd like to convert a field in those documents to another data type.  In my case I have a date string I'd like to recast as a date object, and I know the index of the array item I'd like to update:

```
{
    "_id": 12345,
    "docsArray": [
        { "createdDate": "2008-01-12T07:36:45-08:00" },
        { "createdDate": "2008-01-12T07:36:45-08:00" }
    ]
}
```

When I run the following:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 12345 },
    {
        "$set": {
            "docsArray.0.createdDate": { "$toDate": "$docsArray.0.createdDate" },
        },
    }
)
```

I get:

```
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 52,
                "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$toDate' in 'docsArray.0.createdDate.$toDate' is not valid for storage."
        }
})
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?  I'd like to do this using the $set operator and explicitly referencing the index of the array item to update if possible.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask.

Answer (score 0):

The regular update query can't allow aggregation operators in update part, and the second `docsArray` is an array so regular update query won't work,

try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `docsArray` array and convert `createdDate` from string to date type

```
db.collection.update(
  { _id: "12345" },
  [{
    $set: {
      docsArray: {
        $map: {
          input: "$docsArray",
          in: { createdDate: { $toDate: "$$this.createdDate" } }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qcBOz-pa9Xd)